# Conform to a protocol and use self as argument in another class initializer that takes that protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, init, self

I try to instantiate a new class (MyService) that takes a protocol (MyProtocol) as an argument in its' initializer. The class that instantiate MyService conforms to MyProtocol and therefore I try to use `self` as argument. But this doesn't work and I get a compiler error in the file MyService.swift on the following line:

```
let service = MyService(delegate: self)
```

MyService.swift:

```
import Foundation

protocol MyProtocol {
    func handle()
}

class MyService {
    let delegate: MyProtocol

    init(delegate: MyProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

MyClass.swift:

```
import Foundation

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    let service = MyService(delegate: self)

    func handle() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error you're getting? Please include anything that's going to help us diagnose and fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you can't use self in the constant declaration, since at that point you don't still have a self. You have a self once all the needed variables are initialized and calls to super.init made, not before that.

The best way to achieve it is to change it to a variable with an assumed value that will be set during initialization, at the end of it actually:

```
protocol MyProtocol : class {
  func handle()
}

class MyService {

  var delegate: MyProtocol

  init(delegate: MyProtocol) {
    self.delegate = delegate
  }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {

  var service:MyService!

  init() {
    service = MyService(delegate: self)
  }

  func handle() {
    NSLog("handle")
  }
}
```

You can also make the variable a lazy one instead of using the init method, as suggested by Christopher Swasey:

```
class MyClass : MyProtocol {

  lazy var service:MyService = MyService(delegate: self)

  func handle() {
    NSLog("handle")
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I change `MyProtocol` to be a class instance I get another error in MyClass.swift: `Use of unresolved identifier self`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: I'll edit the answer to address that: too long for a comment

Comment: If you're gonna change it to var, might as well define it as `lazy var service : MyService = MyService(delegate: self)` (relying on type inference will trigger a compiler error complaining about `self`)

Comment: The closure isn't necessary, although I thought it was for quite a while. Presumably it's @autoclosure behind the scenes. One more note: If you're always setting the var in `init` there's no need for it to be an implicitly unwrapped optional (conversely, one of the two should be `weak var` which does have to be an optional of some form)

Comment: You're right again, since it's a simple initialization it doesn't require the closures. The variable is lazily initialized and that automatically means that self will be available by then.

Comment: Regarding the use of implicitly unwrapped optional in the first solution, it's needed because the initialization of the variable requires self which is not available util the variable is initialized: deadlock. The only way to avoid it is to make implicitly unwrapped so you can use self to initialize it.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I forgot about the fact that it was involving `self`, despite that being the entire point of the question!

Comment: "Swift doesn't know what type of object will be the one that implements MyProtocol, and thus cannot tell the appropriate way to store it (by reference, by value,...)." I don't think this is true. You can definitely have variables of protocol type which isn't marked `class`.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit the answer to remove that part. It works without marking the protocol as class only. That's only needed when you need class semantics (reference type), and this is not the case.